# How to get rid of weird lines behind grease pencil strokes?

Tags: grease-pencil

Im a beginner animator in Blender, I was writing the storyboard for my new cartoon and after a certain time my strokes in blender started having these weird black (vectors??) lines behind each grease pencil stroke. I've been told its a graphic card issue but Im pretty sure its not, considering that my other animation files dont have this same problem. Most likely its a hotkey I probably pressed but who knows for sure. This is a screenshot of whats happening. Any help is appreciated thank you! [image]

Comment: This could be a brush issue such as anti-alias

Comment: would I just fix that using the brush settings?

Comment: Try it, Brandon Gomez. I hardly use grease pencil and speak from non-Blender 2D p.o.v.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a specific fix for this problem yet, but that's meant to happen for wireframe mode strictly (or shading preview mode with wireframe mode on). The only thing you can do to remove them while in wireframe mode is to hide overlays.